# "You are one of those people who correct me." Why we don't use "one of them"?

Tags: difference, pronouns

> You are one of those people who correct me.

I have confusion regarding the use of "one of them" and "one of those". Why we don't use "one of them"? Please explain it.

Comment: Are you asking "why don't we say 'one of them people who correct me'?

Answer (score -1):

I think the relative pronoun who is preceded by  noun or a pronoun in subjective case.

> **You  are one of those people who  correct me**

We say **it is I who am to blame**

We do not say:

**It is me who am to blame**

so  **you are one  of those   people who  correct me**      but not

**you are one  of them  people who  correct me.**

This, that , these and those have no objective cases though they  may be used  as  objects  or subjects. They are demonstrative pronouns and they  may be followed by nouns.

One of them people is wrong because **them** is a personal pronoun which can not follow any noun or a relative pronoon.

.

Comment: I hope  the user who down voted the answer should say  why it  was down voted